# TreeTable bindRows factory function don't work

Tags: html, jquery, sapui5

I have TreeTable in my App implemented. In my Controller i want to bind there my rows and in it i have a factory function with a console.log in it. But it doesn't work, can you please help me ?

my Code is:

```
oTreeTable.bindRows({
            path: "/xy",
            parameters: {   
                navigation: { 
                    "xy" : "xyz",
                    "xyzs" : "yz"   

                }
            },
            factory: function (sId,oContext){

                console.log(sId);

            }});
```

The same thing work for bindColumns very well, but for bindRows i dont understand why it not go into the factory function.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

sap.ui.table.*Table controls do not support factory for the row binding. This is the main architectural difference with the sap.m.Table. To work with millions of record with scrolling virtualization sap.ui.table.*Table has to know all the rows have the same template so that it can simply apply the binding context on the existing rows.